# Spring RequestBody map JSON string to Point2D coordinates

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I want to map an incoming JSON string to a custom POJO in my `@PostMapping`:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/classification", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getClassificationResults (
            @RequestBody Classification classification) {

     this.elasticSearchService.getSpatialData(classification);
  return ResponseEntity.ok(" ");
}
```

My `classification POJO`:

```java
public class Classification {
    @JsonProperty
    private ArrayList<Point2D.Double> shapes;
    @JsonProperty
    private String [] colors;
    @JsonProperty
    private String [] pattern;
    @JsonProperty
    private Integer size;
...
}
```

which (of course) results in the error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
>   `java.awt.geom.Point2D$Double` (although at least one Creator exists):
>   no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from
>   String value

Data example:

```
"[[8.880321034663876,49.121984026160106], 
 [8.746452886806255,49.11327654230291], 
 [8.61786489671323,49.087497674922325],...]"
```

My resulting object must not be an `ArrayList` of `Point2D` objects, but rather any type of `Array` which contains the same values as the example - just converted to number.

Do I have to specify my own Jackson deserializer (how can I do this?) for this problem, or is it sufficient to change the `Classification` constructor?

Comment: I don't believe simply modifying your `Classification` class will work here.  The problem here is that it's an array of 2 doubles.  The mapper has no idea which one is 'x', which one is 'y', or that they're even related (not in a joined object, they're independent elements of an array).  If it were me I'd roll with my own deserializer (and my own `Point` class), but whatever's easiest for your application should suffice.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, that's the 'point' ;D
How can I create a custom deserializer? - maybe with jackson, as this is supported by Spring.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement custom deserialiser or using [MixIn feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) define [Shape.ARRAY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Shape.html#ARRAY) for `Point2D` class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JsonMapper jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addMixIn(Point2D.Double.class, Point2DDoubleMixIn.class)
                .build();

        String json = "[[8.880321034663876,49.121984026160106],[8.746452886806255,49.11327654230291],[8.61786489671323,49.087497674922325]]";

        TypeReference<List<Point2D.Double>> type = new TypeReference<List<Point2D.Double>>() {};
        List<Point2D.Double> shapes = jsonMapper.readValue(json, type);
        System.out.println(shapes);
    }
}

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
interface Point2DDoubleMixIn { }
```

See also:

- [Specifying the Shape](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat#4-specifying-the-shape).